# Express.js Cannot get result from query mysql using async await

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I dont know why this code not working. if i use this code always returning error message.

result :

> {
>       "error": true,
>       "message": "error from query category" }

iam just want to get my data from database using async and await function

iam using express.js && mysql.js

**In my Controller :**

```
export const getAllCategory = async (req, res) => {
    let sql = `select * from categories order by id desc`;
    try {
        let result = await db.query(sql);
        return res.status(200).json(result);
        // db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        //     return res.status(200).json(result);
        // })
        //    return res.status(201).json(query);
        // // return res.status(201).json({ error: false, data:query});
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'error from query category' });
    }
}
```

**Router**

```
const routes = new Router();

routes.post('/category/create',CategoryController.createCategory);
routes.get('/category/getall', CategoryController.getAllCategory);
export default routes;
```

before that iam try to use this code and its working. but i think using async await is very good so i try to use it but i dont know how its work

```
  db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        return res.status(200).json(result);
    })
```

its that because i dont return the result? or i cant do that using async await?

Answer (score 0):

async await works with method that return promise. db.query function takes callback so async await will not work in this case